# Call member function of non-active union member

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, unions

Does calling `foo` in the following code leads to UB?

```cpp
using vec = std::array<int, 1>;
struct field0 {
    vec data;
    operator int() {
        return data[0];
    }
};

union a {
    struct {
        vec data;
    } data;
    field0 x;
};

void foo() {
    a bar;
    std::cin >> bar.data.data[0];
    std::cout << bar.x;
}
```

According to standard, `x` and `data` have the same address, so it should be safe to cast `this` to `vec*`. Also, `field0` and `vec` are layout-compatible, so it should be safe to inspect `data` via `x.data` or vice-versa.

However, we not just inspect `x.data`, we call non-static member function of `x` outside of it's lifetime (or do we? I can't find a reason why `x` lifetime should have started), so formally it's UB. Is it correct?

What I am trying to achieve is well-defined version of common approach to name array field like `union a { int data[3]; int x, y, z};`

UPD:

1. Sorry, during removing unnecessary details, layout compatibility between array field and "getter" was lost. Restored now.
2. I will need to use `a` values to function that takes `int*`, so going in other direction - declaring fields and overloading `operator[]` - is not an option.

Comment: Accessing anything except the active member of a union is UB. Plain and simple. I don't see any way you could make this valid.

Comment: the named array field thingy may be common in C, but I have never seen it in C++. You can use references to get something similar without risking UB

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's not entirely correct.  You are allowed to access the common initial sequence of standard layout classes, but there is no common initial sequence  here.

Comment: _so formally it's UB._  You are correct.  Don't do that, or you risk nasal demons.

Comment: If you want to decompose an array of 3 members into named values you could use [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Comment: Sorry, I somehow lost the common initial sequence (restored now), and I am pretty sure that `bar.x.data[0]` would be correct (or am I wrong here?..). @JesperJuhl thanks, structured binding would be good idea if I would need all fields at once, but I need them only one at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.  The initial common sequence rule wont help you here since you are not accessing a common member but instead you are accessing the entire object in order to call the member function<sup>1</sup>.

> What I am trying to achieve is well-defined version of common approach to name array field like `union a { int data[3]; int x, y, z};`

The way to do this in C++ is to use a struct and operator overloading.  Instead of having an array and trying to map it to individual members, you have individual members and then pretend that your class is an array.  That looks like

```
struct vec
{
    int x, y, z;
    int& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        switch(index)
        {
        case 0: return x;
        case 1: return y;
        case 2: return z;
        }
    }
};
```

<sup>1: to call a member function is to pass that object to that function as if it was the first parameter of the function.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, somehow the initial common sequence was lost during question formulation, restored now. Also should have say that I need to guarantee that fields are sequential (to get `int*` with natural semantics from my structure). And anyway, for some reason compiler doesn't recognize that this switch can be optimized to simple addition of addresses, so generates usual jump table https://godbolt.org/z/VLstmr