# aliasing access to individual array members

Tags: c++

I have a set of ints that i need to access as an array and also have nice aliases for specifc ones.

I have

```
std::array<int,10> numbers;
```

I can clearly do

```
int n2 = numbers[2];
```

but numbers[2] represent (lets say) width of noodle

would be nice to be able to code

```
int twidth = width;
```

I know I can go

```
    const WIDTH = 2;
...
    int width = numbers[WIDTH]
```

or (aarrgh)

```
#define width numbers[2]
```

or

```
int width()
{
    return numbers[2];
}
```

But none of those seems quite right. I wonder if there is some c++ construct I don't know or have forgotten about (I just discovered the joy of using instead of typedef)

Comment: What is wrong with using `int width() { return numbers[2]; }`? Clear, concise, not subject to user error, etc. The only thing missing is it should be marked as `const`: `int width() const { return numbers[2]; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau free functions cannot be marked as `const`.

Comment: @NathanOliver True. I was assuming the array is a data member of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a reference.

```
const auto& width = numbers[2];

// use width here for whatever you want as a read only value.
```

If you want to be able to change the value, then just drop the `const` so you have

```
auto& width = numbers[2];
```

---

If you want to provide names for all of the elements of the array, you can use a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to make it easier like

```
const auto& [name1, name2, name3, ..., name10] = numbers;
```

Comment: having `const int WidthPos = 2` would also help, with `const auto& width = numbers[WidthPos];`

Comment: the structured binding one wont work inside a class (numbers is a class member and I need the 'aliases' to be too. First one is fine though - ty

Comment: @pm100 In that case, you might be instrested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62089026/4342498) solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the straight-forward answer, look at [@NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477096/8038186). But I think that if you can change the array structure into something else, it'll be a better approach for this situation. For example, you can use `struct` to map your vlaues:

```
struct data {
    int something, ///< Description
        width, ///< Description
        height, ///< Description
        something2; ///< Description
}

int main() {
    data my_data;
    my_data.width = 20;
    std::cout << my_data.width << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are pros and cons for this solution (for example, to print all the values you'll have to work a little bit harder).

If you still want to go with the array solution, I want to add one more option to @NathanOliver solutions:

```
enum positions_map : int {
    TPYE_1: 0,
    SOMETHING: 1,
    WIDTH: 2,
    HEIGHT: 3,
    SOMETHING_2: 4,
    ...
}

// ...

auto& width = numbers[WIDTH];

// ...
```